# SWT tree multiple icons

Tags: java, swt

I am trying to add multiple icons for the swt tree by appending more images into one long image and then adding it for each tree node. The problem is that the dashed line is elongated more and more as the width of the image increases(see the picture). I tried to add paint listeners but I am having some repainting problem, so the paint listeners don't work for me.
If anyone has any suggestions, please help.

[image]

```java
switch (event.type) {
    case SWT.MeasureItem: {
        final Object value = ((TreeItem) event.item).getData();
        final BrowserNode node = getBrowserNode(value);
        Image image = getCombinedImage(node.getImage1(),node.getImage2(),node.getImage3(),node.getImage4());
        Rectangle rect = image.getBounds();
        event.width += rect.width;// rect.width*2;
        event.height = Math.max(event.height, rect.height + 2);
        break;
    }
    case SWT.PaintItem: {
        BrowserNode node = getBrowserNode(((TreeItem) event.item).getData());
        Image image = getCombinedImage(node.getImage1(),node.getImage2(),node.getImage3(),node.getImage4());
        Rectangle rect = image.getBounds();
        int offset = Math.max(0, (event.height - rect.height) / 2);
        event.gc.copyArea(event.x, event.y, event.width, event.height, event.x + image.getImageData().width-30, event.y + offset, false);
        event.gc.fillRectangle(event.x, event.y, image.getImageData().width, event.height);
        event.gc.drawImage(image, event.x, event.y + offset);
        break;
    }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see a difference between the icons on the left and on the right in the image. Can you post a standalone snippet that produces the unwanted dashed lines?

Comment: The space between vertical dashed line and the plus is to big for the children items. Also the size for the horizontal dashed line is too big.<br/>  
I'm trying to customize:
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree
to obtain the behavior on the right side.

Comment: But what code led to the right side, or is the right side a drawing program mock?

Comment: This looks indeed strange. I've uploaded a modified Tree snippet here: http://pastebin.com/DqnATDnG

Comment: It looks like your image bounds have extra space to the left. check getCombinedImage() method.

Comment: I tried your code, but i'm still getting the same result. Did it worked for you?

Comment: Could you add a picture with the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The excessive indentation of tree nodes is specific to Windows, other platforms do not behave this way.

This issue is discussed in this bug report:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=185004

The suggested workaround is to draw the tree items yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think that you are right, but i'll have to test it. I will mark the answer as correct tomorrow, if it works.